# Как выделить из строки числа?

Tags: javascript

В массиве есть множество строк вида: `"\\*.{5,8}" и "\\*.{3}"` (с разными значениями)

Есть две переменные x1 и x2.

---

В цикле случайно выбираем например строку `"\\*.{5,8}"`
Можно ли как-то записать значение **5** из этой строки в переменную **x1**, а значение **8** в переменную **x2**?

И если в цикле случайно выбираем например строку `"\\*.{3}"`
Можно ли как-то записать значение **3** из этой строки в переменную **x1 и x**2?

Comment: можно *(5 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor извините, можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    str = ['\\*.{5,8}', '\\*.{3}'];
    res = [];
    str.forEach(function(x) {
       found = x.match(/{(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?}/);
       if(found) {
          res.push([found[1], found[2]||found[1]])
       }
    })
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, если не трудно, можете прокомментировать код

Comment: @Бармалей всё или только регулярку?

Comment: можно только регулярку)

Comment: там я думаю лучше, чем я, объясняют :) https://regex101.com/r/3cmLSE/1

Comment: Большое спасибо!